# Javascript Amcharts Exports

Tags: fusioncharts, amcharts

Is there any way to export the javascript amcharts like FusionXT charts ?

http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/?exporting-image/ECPureJS.html

Comment: like this http://blog.amcharts.com/2012/09/exporting-javascript-charts-maps-as.html ? http://jsfiddle.net/maertz/qf5m3/  http://jsfiddle.net/maertz/bbTKg/

Comment: Yes.But i am not able implement this in IE8 ,because this works fine in SVG supporting browser .

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Review the AmCharts Export plugin repository on github, which includes api details.

- https://github.com/amcharts/export

Also review this article from the amCharts website:

- [Exporting charts and maps: Quick Intro](https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/intro-exporting-charts/)

The export options from the plugin are highly configurable; in addition, the tool allows annotation of charts.

Once you include the export plugin js and css files, the default configuration only needs you to set the "export" to be enabled in the amChart config.

```
type: "serial",
theme: "light",
...
export: {
  enabled: true
}
```

Here is an a fiddle example based on Version: 1.4.33 of the export plugin (sorry, had to manually add the js and css).

- https://jsfiddle.net/Lm2zptar/2/

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]